# Blood on Different Planet

Tags: science-based, xenobiology, biochemistry

A planet that has 56% nitrogen, 40% oxygen, and 3% sulfuric dioxide has life on it. The most efficient color of blood on Earth is red iron based blood. What would be the most efficient pigment for their blood?

Comment: Sulfur isn't a gas below 444C.

Comment: At 40%, oxygen would be a pretty potent oxidizer.

Comment: What's the pressure? Of the three gases mentioned oxygen is by far the most efficient oxidizer. And anyway diatomic nitrogen is pretty much inert.

Comment: @sphennings Looks like we went from 3% S to 3% SO$_2$. With a boiling point of -10°C (at standard pressure, I presume), you wouldn't want the planet to get too cold, but at least it's a gas under many circumstances...

Comment: Are you _sure_ that the most efficient "color" of blood is red? What does that even mean? In the hypothesis that you mean "pigment", did you know that [cephalopods use hemocyanin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cephalopod#Circulatory_system) (with copper instead of iron) and therefore their blood is blue when oxygenated?

Comment: Arget, please avoid editing to change what you are asking. (It's always annoying to have the question change under your feet.) You would be better off deciding what you want to know, researching that a bit, then ask about whatever you fail to grasp, *while showing that you have tried yourself before asking for help*. Also, now that you have earned a bit of reputation from your previous question, you may want to try the [question sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4835/29) on [meta] where many issues can be worked out before you post the question on the main site.

Comment: I know what colors of blood their is on Earth, and the reason for it, but this is for a planet that is not Earth.

Comment: Okay, so now we've gone from oxidizer, through changing from sulfur to sulfur dioxide in the atmosphere, to a "base" for blood, to a pigment. What's next? I think this is starting to qualify as a [chameleon question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/157730).

Comment: I would strongly suggest to get rid of the sulphur dioxide. It has a nasty tendency to combine with water vapor giving sulphurous acid (and some sulphuric acid). At 3% in the atmosphere and Earth-like pressure and temperature that would make for very very corrosive [acid rain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acid_rain).

Comment: @AlexP OP is aware of that, see [previous question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/79626/29).

Comment: The question sandbox is nice to know about, so thanks.

Comment: There's no real reason (AFAIK) to think that red is the "most efficient" color of blood - that's not how evolution works.  Rather, some ancestor of the vertebrates developed hemoglobin-based blood, and it was good enough to do the job so it was conserved.  A different random evolutionary twist, and we might have had blue blood, or clear, like some invertebrates.  Or someone with extensive knowledge of biochemistry might design a more efficient blood that is green or purple...

Comment: @Michael it's not really a chameleon unless it got changed after someone answered. Of course if you started to write an answer, I can see how this is annoying.

Comment: @Mołot I know it technically isn't a chameleon question until it keeps changing in response to answers, but such repeat changes as we have already seen on this one makes at least me unwilling to take the time to research and write an answer. At the very least, it hints that the OP doesn't really know themselves what they want to know.

Answer (score 1):

Blood is red because of the way iron and oxygen interact in the hemoglobin, not because of pigment. To know what colour the blood should be, you'd have to design your own hemoglobin equivalent to fit that environment and work out what colour it would be. That's a lot of work, but if you want to do it, more power to you